# how to check user attribute every time user pass through the authorization handler in net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a local user authentication and password has to expire after 20 days. I added attribute LastPasswordChangedDate in ApplicationUser and I wrote a function to check if the password has not expired. Could you advise me what task should I override to execute the pasword check every time user pass through the authorization handler?

```
    public IActionResult CheckUserPasswordExparation(ApplicationUser appUser, string returnUrl)
{
    if (appUser.LastPasswordChangedDate.AddDays(PasswordExpireDays) < DateTime.Now)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "Manage");
    }
    return RedirectToAction(returnUrl);
}
```

I'm checking the password lifetime in a few critical functions. I also hide the menu. I think this is only a workaround. I'm still searching. When I find the solution I will let know. I added this thread on the forum becasue for the time being I'm not happy with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

For checking whether the user's password is expired, you could call `CheckUserPasswordExparation` in the login process. There is no need to call this in `Authorize Handler` which will be called every time for accessing `Authorized Resources`.

In addition, while in `AuthorizationHandler`, you could not call `RedirectToAction`. You only could call `context.Fail();`in `HandleRequirementAsync` while the password is expired to indicate the authorization is fail.

Comment: This solution allow user to get access to system resources for instance using direct url. I need to block the access permanently until the password change.

Comment: @Lukas it checks the password in login, if the user fail to login, he will also fail to access secure resource. What do you mean it will allow user to access resources using direct url?

Comment: To change the password user have to be loged in. While password expaired the user is loged in and redirected to change password. But user can use for instance a link from boomarks to skip passord change process.

Comment: @Lukas if so, you could check the password expaired while token validate. What I need to note you, you could not redirect from `AuthorizationHandler`.

Comment: I'm looking for smart solution to solve this case ;)

Comment: @Lukas What is your expected smart solution? Or, what is the limit by checking the token for you?

Comment: I'm checking the password lifetime in a few critical functions. I also hide the menu. I think this is only a workaround. I'm still searching. When I find the solution I will let know. I added this thread on the forum becasue for the time being I'm not happy with my solution.